# C++ Not getting expected result when executing a Macro

Tags: c++, macros, swap, operator-precedence, command-precedence

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define swapOut(a,b) a+b-a, a+b-b

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;

    printf("%d,%d", swapOut(a+b,b-a));
    
    return 0;
}
```

When executing this program, I am expecting the output to be "1,11", but the actual output is "13,1". Can someone explain what is happening here ?

Comment: Although still imperfect, you can change the definition of `swapOut(a, b)` to be `(b), (a)` to achieve the same meaning more reliably.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's happening, you have to realise that macros are not like functions; they perform very simple text substitution. Thus, when you define

```
#define swapOut(a,b) a+b-a, a+b-b
```

and then use it as `swapOut(a+b,b-a)`, it is expanded as `a+b+b-a-a+b, a+b+b-a-b-a`. With the values `a=5` and `b=6` this results in `13,1`.

So here's a valuable lesson: *always surround the arguments in macros with parentheses*. The corrected version of your program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define swapOut(a,b) ((a)+(b)-(a)), ((a)+(b)-(b))

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;

    printf("%d,%d", swapOut(a+b,b-a));

   return 0;
}
```

This indeed outputs `1,11` as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you have to localize the value first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define swapOut(a,b) a+b-a, a+b-b

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    int c = a + b;
    int d = b - a;
    
    printf("%d,%d", swapOut(c,d));
    
    return 0;
}
```